# Cannot view Cloudformation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I just got access of Sandbox AWS account.I wanted to go through some of the CloudFormation templates.I could see there are lot of cloudformation stacks already created and i can see its Stackinfo,Events,resources,Parameters,Outputs etc.
Current status of stacks is either create_complete or Update_complete.

But when i click on template tab i got

```
    "The stack is in review.After you create the stack,you can view its 
       template here".
```

What could be the reason its not allowing me to view the template ?

Comment: Is it a permissions issue. What happens if you try to retrieve it via the CLI?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/get-template.html

Comment: Are you able to create a new stack and view it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to view the cloudformation template by clicking on the 'change sets' tab as the Cloudformation resource was created, but the template hasn't been applied.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets.html

Comment: @Stevan T ,I clicked on changed sets but it say "No change sets to display"